# Set FormGroup to FormArray at specific Index

Tags: angular

I want to insert/push formgroup of controls in formarray at specific index. I tried to commands of FormArray like insert/setControl but they happen to insert at index 0,1,2 and i wish to insert at index 0,10,20,11 as per logic. Please help me find a way as new to angular reactive forms.

Comment: add example here https://stackblitz.com

Comment: you can use an Object to map your indexes with the required indexes something like this {0:0, 10:1, 20:2}

Comment: @Ankit can you please help with a example.

Comment: @Ahmed i have formgroup of controls that i need to push in a form array at specific index like 0,10,20 pattern but every time i use insert indexes of formgroup is 0,1,2...

Comment: @NishthaGupta I can't understand well what are you need. but I think this example can help you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

Comment: @Ahmed, i went through this, see if u notice down it uses .push function which adds formgroup always at index 0,1,2 bt if  i replace it with insert(index,formgroup) it work same.. i am looking to insert not to insert by default at these index.

Comment: @Ahmed, i made changes to link kindly check the output in console and comment added for better understanding of question - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-a4x25r

Comment: @NishthaGupta check this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-kb8frg